# Edit multiple meshes at once?

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode

I want to edit a game model and I can't join the meshes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> because the model will not work in the game anymore. If I use <kbd>P</kbd> in *Edit Mode*, the meshes will split into even more meshes than before, with different names, and it will not work anymore.

The model is separated into multiple meshes.
I can edit the vertices of each mesh, but I can't edit multiple meshes at once, so that they stay "synchronized".

Any idea how to do this without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> or a way to "unjoin" keeping the same meshes names before joining?

Comment: one sec. why won't it work if you join it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an addon called [MultiEdit](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?339369-MultiEdit-ALPHA-2%28Major-Update%29-Multiple-Objects-Editing), that will enable you to edit multiple objects at once.
[Here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?339369-MultiEdit-ALPHA-2%28Major-Update%29-Multiple-Objects-Editing) is the post on blender artists where the download can be found.

After you have [installed and activated](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Add-Ons) the addon, you just select the objects that you want to edit together, and click on the *MultiEdit Enter* button in the tool shelf.
Then when you are done, toggle back out of edit mode and click on the *MultiEdit Exit* button.

Answer (score 4):

And 4 years later blender 2.8 has this feature built in :)

Comment: Oh great! I'll test that!